# The compiled aosp8.1.0_r4 flushes to pixel2, and the error "CHRE: Failed to start CHRE on SLPI: 59" loops all the time

Tags: android, android-source

```
01-31 20:41:05.990  5171  5171 E CHRE    : Failed to start CHRE on SLPI: 59
01-31 20:41:10.949  5174  5174 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:10.949  5174  5174 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:10.951  5174  5174 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:10.951  5174  5174 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:10.951  5174  5174 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:571: Error 3b: remote handle invoke failed. domain 2, handle ffffffff, sc 5020000, pra 0x7fd36b6178
01-31 20:41:10.951  5174  5174 E CHRE    : Failed to deliver timestamp message from host to CHRE: 59
01-31 20:41:10.956  5174  5174 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:10.956  5174  5174 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:10.961  5174  5174 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:10.961  5174  5174 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:10.961  5174  5174 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:571: Error 3b: remote handle invoke failed. domain 2, handle ffffffff, sc 0, pra 0x0
01-31 20:41:10.961  5174  5174 E CHRE    : Failed to start CHRE on SLPI: 59
01-31 20:41:15.947  5177  5177 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:15.947  5177  5177 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:15.952  5177  5177 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:15.952  5177  5177 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:15.952  5177  5177 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:571: Error 3b: remote handle invoke failed. domain 2, handle ffffffff, sc 5020000, pra 0x7ff6837c68
01-31 20:41:15.952  5177  5177 E CHRE    : Failed to deliver timestamp message from host to CHRE: 59
01-31 20:41:15.955  5177  5177 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:15.955  5177  5177 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:15.957  5177  5177 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:15.957  5177  5177 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:15.957  5177  5177 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:571: Error 3b: remote handle invoke failed. domain 2, handle ffffffff, sc 0, pra 0x0
01-31 20:41:15.957  5177  5177 E CHRE    : Failed to start CHRE on SLPI: 59
01-31 20:41:20.952  5180  5180 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:20.952  5180  5180 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:20.958  5180  5180 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:20.958  5180  5180 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:20.958  5180  5180 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:571: Error 3b: remote handle invoke failed. domain 2, handle ffffffff, sc 5020000, pra 0x7fd1fb6ed8
01-31 20:41:20.958  5180  5180 E CHRE    : Failed to deliver timestamp message from host to CHRE: 59
01-31 20:41:20.962  5180  5180 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:20.963  5180  5180 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:20.967  5180  5180 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:20.967  5180  5180 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:20.967  5180  5180 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:571: Error 3b: remote handle invoke failed. domain 2, handle ffffffff, sc 0, pra 0x0
01-31 20:41:20.967  5180  5180 E CHRE    : Failed to start CHRE on SLPI: 59
01-31 20:41:25.968  5183  5183 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:25.968  5183  5183 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:25.970  5183  5183 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1038: Error ffffffff: apps_dev_init failed. domain 2, errno Operation not permitted
01-31 20:41:25.970  5183  5183 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:1113: Error ffffffff: open dev -1 for domain 2 failed
01-31 20:41:25.970  5183  5183 D /vendor/bin/chre: vendor/qcom/proprietary/adsprpc/src/fastrpc_apps_user.c:571: Error 3b: remote handle invoke failed. domain 2, handle ffffffff, sc 5020000, pra 0x7fe064e218
01-31 20:41:25.970  5183  5183 E CHRE    : Failed to deliver timestamp message from host to CHRE: 59
```

I didn't make any changes to aosp. This error report looks like Qualcomm's driver is reporting an error.

https://developers.google.com/android/drivers?hl=zh-cn#walleyeopm1.171019.013

Comment: Make sure you flash the same stock firmware images (factory images) on both the slots, before you flash your own builds!

Comment: Thanks. Your method is fine. I flash google's official image (OPM1.171019.013), and then I flashed my own again. @RajatGupta